# Programmatically done UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have two views. In the first view I have a table and on selection of a row I call the 2nd view like the following code. The code for the called class is also given. But somehow I can only see the chnaged background and not the other UIImageView that is there. Can anyone please kindly help me out ?? Thanks.

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    details.movieName2=movieName;
    self.title=@"Back";
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:NO];    
}
```

The view class header :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface detailedView : UIViewController {
    NSString *movieName2;
    UIImageView *myImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *movieName2;
@end
```

And the view class code is :

```
#import "detailedView.h"

@implementation detailedView

@synthesize movieName2;
@synthesize myImageView;

- (id) init {
    self=[super init];
    movieName2=@"";    
    myImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] init];

return self;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 355, 615);
    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background-retina.png"]];

    self.title=self.movieName2;    

    [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]];
    [myImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 50, 50)];
    [self.view addSubview:myImageView]; 
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [myImageView release];
    [movieName2 release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: Side note, `details.movieName2=[movieName retain];` is over-retaining it. `details.movieName2=movieName;` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting movie name after you push the detail controller

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:details animated:NO]; 
details.movieName2=[movieName retain];
```

**UPDATE**

@Ahsan whatever you are doing is wrong. When you tap on tableViewCell that time you need to allocate second view or if you have already allocated detailsView then why you are allocating a newView in viewDidAppear. Try commenting the line

```
self.view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

and see if it works. The background is works because you are settings the background color by in detailsView itself. The problem is with the allocating a new View and assiging of that view to self.view.

Comment: @Rahul : See, the 2nd view is called and the background is set accordingly. Its only the UIImageView that is causing the problem :(

Comment: @Rahul : nope, doesnt work...but UILabel works. Any idea why ? :(

Comment: @Ahsan did you update your code? could you please post the complete method like tableViewDidSelectRow and further what you are doing in the details view. Also make sure to bind everything properly in interface builder

Comment: @Rahul : Apart from the code given for ViewDidSelectRow, I am doing some NSLogs. For the details view controller, also similar: other stuffs I am just initializing (but not doing anything). I am not using the IB. Trying to do the UI programmatically !

Comment: @Ahsan did you try to debug your app? make sure this line is executed properly [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]]; try to seperate them like  this UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"]; then see if it is returning a UIImage object or nil. if UIImage object is nil then you don't have that image in your application's bundle. If it returning a UIImage Object then set  like this [myImageView setImage:img];. Also make sure myImageView should not be nil